# How can I skip 'Scan-error: "Unbalanced parentheses"...'?

Tags: balanced-parentheses, sexp

I want to write a script in order to correct spaces inside section command in a LaTeX code, that's to say

```
\section{Lorem ipsum dolor
  sit amet consectetuer adipiscing
  elit}
```

should be

```
\section{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit}
```

I do this with the following script:

```
(defun headings-on-same-line ()
  "Delete new lines inside section commands."
  (interactive)

  (goto-char (point-min))

  (while (search-forward "\\section" nil t)
    (setq sec1 (make-marker))
    (set-marker sec1 (point))
    (set-marker-insertion-type sec1 t)
    (forward-sexp)
    (setq sec2 (make-marker))
    (set-marker sec2 (point))
    (set-marker-insertion-type sec2 t)

    (perform-replace "\\(?:[ ]*\\)?
\\(?:[ ]*\\)?"
             " " t t nil 1 nil sec1 sec2)

    ))
```

I have problems with unbalanced parentheses like this:

```
\section{Lorem ipsum $(a\rangle$
   dolor sit amet
   consectetuer adipiscing elit}
```

I have thought to use an `if-else` construct, so I have rewritten the code above like this:

```
(defun headings-on-same-line-unbalanced ()
  "Delete new lines inside section commands."
  (interactive)

  (goto-char (point-min))

  (while (search-forward "\\section" nil t)
    (setq sec1 (make-marker))
    (set-marker sec1 (point))
    (set-marker-insertion-type sec1 t)
    (if (forward-sexp)
    (progn
      (setq sec2 (make-marker))
      (set-marker sec2 (point))
      (set-marker-insertion-type sec2 t)

      (perform-replace "\\(?:[ ]*\\)?
\\(?:[ ]*\\)?"
               " " t t nil 1 nil sec1 sec2)
      )
  (progn
    (insert "Warning"))
  )))
```

but it does not work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Basically use `(skip-chars-forward "^}")`
Needs a helper-function, to check if it's a escaped }:

```
(defun ar-backslashed-p ()
  (save-excursion
    (and (eq (char-before) ?\\)
     (< 0 (% (abs (skip-chars-backward (regexp-quote (char-to-string ?\\)) (line-beginning-position))) 2)))))

(defun no-newline-in-section ()
  (interactive "*")
  (let (beg end)
    (while (search-forward "\\section" nil t)
      (when (and (eq (char-after) ?{)
         (not (ar-backslashed-p)))
    (setq beg (point))
    (while (and (or (< 0 (abs (skip-chars-forward "^}")))(eq (char-after) ?}))
            (eq (char-after) ?})
            (or
             ;; check for nested braces
             (< 1 (nth 0 (parse-partial-sexp beg (point))))
            (ar-backslashed-p))
            (progn (forward-char 1) t)))
    (when (eq (char-after) ?})
      (save-restriction
        (narrow-to-region beg (point))
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (while (search-forward "\n" nil t 1)
          (replace-match ""))))))))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Sometimes I have sections with `{...}' inside their arguments. Do you know how to do in this case?

Comment: @OnnerIrotsab You mean nested braces?

Comment: Yes, something like this: `\section{Lorem $x^{4}$ ipsum~(\ref{eq}) dolor $x_{\text{1-loop}}$}`.

Comment: @OnnerIrotsab Should handle nested braces now.

Comment: Ok, if I combine this new code with the previous one, all works fine, thank you!